# How do call this method to bind it to an Infragistics control?

Tags: c#, infragistics, webdatagrid

This method correctly loads the data and binds it to the infragistics control as long as I remove the object source, EventArgs e and call the method from page_load.

Is that a good idea to remove the object source, eventArgs e?

```
protected void dgvAppts_NeedDataSource(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session.IsNewSession == false)
            {
                DataTable ApptTable = new DataTable();
                ApptTable = objGatewayFunctions.GetAppointmentReCap(Session["LoginID"].ToString(), RecapDate.ToShortDateString(), "R", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"].ToString());
                this.dgvAppts.DataSource = ApptTable;
                //if (ApptTable.Rows.Count == 0)
                //{
                //    this.uwtTabs.Tabs(0).Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    this.uwtTabs.Tabs(0).Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                //}
            }
        }
```

If it's better to have the object source, EventArgs e present in the method.  How do I call that function so it can load the WebDataGrid?

Comment: Was "NeedDataSource(object source, EventArgs e)" an originally an event handler for other control?

Comment: It is being re-written from vb.Net.  and it was an event handler in vb.net.  Trying to convert it over to c# with little knowledge of vb.net. @Trekstuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Infragistics WebDataGrid has NeedDataSource event; it sounds like the code was being converted from the use of a Telerik control.

If that's the case then there's no need to call the method

```
protected void dgvAppts_NeedDataSource(object source, EventArgs e)
```

You can call it instead something like

```
protected void BindMyGrid()
```

and call it from the page load indeed (with possible check to do it only if page is not in a postback mode)

Comment: That was it exactly.  I added it to the Load event instead and it works just fine now.  I can remove the object source, EventArgs and just call it from page load.  That probably makes better sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your method as event handler to `NeedDataSource` event in your grid control.

Select your grid in the designer, open Properties window and select your method as event handler for `NeedDataSource` event.

Looks like the method got detached from the event and that's why you have to call it yourself. It should be the grid control that calls your method when it needs the data source by raising the event.

Comment: The only events for the dgvAppts DataWebGrid are.  CustomDataBinding, DataBinding, DataBound, Disposed, HeaderCheckBoxClicked, Init, InitializeRow, ItemCommand, Load, PreRender and Unload.  Is there a way to add my own event, or should I attack this method to the Init or Load event?

Comment: I attached it to the Load event and it works just fine.  Thank you!